# Zipping a text file on my mac destroys carriage control on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, zip, perforce, carriage-return

I have a file on my Mac which has been run through unix2dos to provide Windows style carriage return.  For example, here's the top part of the file:

```
$ od -c ../README.txt   | head
...
0000020                                                   R   E   A   D
0000040   M   E       f   i   l   e      \r  \n  \r  \n   F   o   r
0000060   c   o   m   p   l   e   t   e       i   n   s   t   r   u   c
```

Then I zip the file on the Mac using the built-in zip program in Lion.  It is zip version 3.0.

But when I open this zip file on Windows, the \r characters have been removed.

```
$ od -c README.txt | head
...
0000020                                                   R   E   A   D
0000040   M   E       f   i   l   e      \n  \n   F   o   r       c   o
```

So in Notepad it appears smashed.

How can I prevent this from occurring?   The concern is that since notepad is the default editor for .txt files on Windows, people will see the smashed version of the file.

Comment: Use another editor than notepad? :p No, seriously, what zip program do you use?

Comment: Question updated - using built-in zip on the Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh!  The root cause was that my source management system (Perforce) was representing the file differently on Windows vs Mac.    The first `od` that I showed above was done on Windows.  I assumed Mac would be the same but it was not; it was the same as the second one.

To resolve this, just before building my zip file on Mac, I used awk to make the file Windows-friendly:

```
cat <sourcefile> | awk 'sub("$", "\r")' > README.txt
```

(You could use unix2dos but I don't have that installed on my build machine.)

Comment: Are you storing the zip file in Perforce? Or storing the source file in Perforce? If you are storing the source file in Perforce, there are a variety of ways to configure and control Perforce's line-ending behaviors: http://kb.perforce.com/article/63

Comment: Storing the input file (sourcefile in my command example above) in Perforce.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have a bug in your zip program. I also use zip version 3 (Gentoo Linux, x86_64) and it does not exhibit this problem:

```
fg@erwin ~ $ file input.txt 
input.txt: HTML document, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
fg@erwin ~ $ stat --format %s input.txt 
476
fg@erwin ~ $ zip -q input.zip input.txt 
fg@erwin ~ $ unzip input.zip 
Archive:  input.zip
replace input.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y
  inflating: input.txt               
fg@erwin ~ $ stat --format %s input.txt 
476
```

Maybe update your zip program, or download the original sources and try with them?

Try and see also whether you have a ZIP or ZIPOPT environment variable (I don't)